# Calling static method on MenuItem Click event

Tags: android, events, static, menuitem

```
onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(particular menuitem selected) {
        //Helper class has static methods isOnline() and showNoConnectionDialog
        if(HelperClass.isOnline(this)) {
            //code ....
        } else {
            HelperClass.showNoConnectionDialog(getApplicationContext());
        }

}
```

The code gives me an error ... when I don't use static methods it works fine ...can anybody help me ...Thanks

Comment: Can you format you code properly and supply more details of the issue

Comment: The Application Stopped unexpectedly ...

Comment: Can you add a LogCat dump of the error? It's kinda hard to create a test app in your case :)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `HelperClass.isOnline(this)` with `HelperClass.isOnline(getApplicationContext())`

Comment: Its working fine in case of Main Menu item but in Sub menu item its not working ..what might be the reason ??